# Kinect pictures come out broken/blotchy

Tags: windows-8, graphics, scanning, kinect

I've been working on connecting my Xbox kinect to a windows 8 Asus computer, I have all the drivers installed, but when I start up a scanner, I get an image like this

[image]

This happens with both skanect and artec studio. I haven't tried any other programs

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/392359/is-windows-kinect-a-different-hardware-from-xbox-kinect?rq=1 may be of interest. I wonder what happens if you get further back

Comment: Someone's posted a more detailed answer as to why - so we have a proper answer, rather than a messy comment thread ;p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xbox kinect is a bit different from the PC version of the Kinect, it can track your movements only when you are a bit farther away from the Kinect. The PC version of the Kinect however can detect you even when you are a bit closer, so if you move back a bit, it will be able to detect you.

From [Microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/kinectforwindows/news/faq.aspx)

> The Kinect for Windows sensor is a fully-tested and supported Kinect
>   experience on Windows with features such as “near mode,” skeletal
>   tracking control, API improvements, and improved USB support across a
>   range of Windows computers and Windows-specific 10’ acoustic models.
>
> The sensor was specifically designed to be used with computers, and
>   includes a shortened USB cable to ensure reliability across a broad
>   range of computers. Kinect for Xbox 360 was built for and tested with
>   the Xbox 360 only, not with any other platform, which is why it is not
>   licensed for general commercial use, supported, or under warranty when
>   used on any other platform.
>
> Kinect for Xbox 360, on the other hand, was built for and tested with
>   the Xbox 360 only, not with any other platform, which is why it is not
>   licensed for general commercial use, supported, or under warranty when
>   used on any other platform.
>
> Microsoft has a large team of engineers that is dedicated to continual
>   improvements of the hardware and software associated with Kinect for
>   Windows, and is committed to providing ongoing access to Microsoft's
>   deep investment in human tracking and speech recognition.